# Proving $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} [1+ (-1)^n a_n] $ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}^2$ uder some conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

This question is from Ponnusamy and silvermann complex variables with applicatio Subsection ( Infinite Products ) and I am struck in 1 part of it.

> Suppose that ${a_n}$ is a decreasing sequence of real numbers with lim $ n\to \infty$ $ a_n =0$ . Show that
> $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}[1+ (-1)^n a_n] $$
> converges iff
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^2 $$
> converges.

I have done the part which assumes convergence of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^2 .$$

For converse , convergence of
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}[1+ (-1)^n a_n]$$
imples convergence of series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$$
converges (let to a). Now , I am unable to use convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$$ to a to prove convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^2 .$$

Kindly help me with that

Comment: And indeed, if $a_n=\frac1{\sqrt {n+1}}$, then $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges, but $\sum a_n^2$ does not.

Comment: the point is that you need to use the much stronger hypothesis of the product convergence; try and show using the convergence of the logarithmic sum and hence its Taylor series that the dominant positive subseries (which is $\sum a_n^2$ up to a multiplicative constant) must converge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $a_n \searrow 0$ and, hence,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^na_n - \log(1+(-1)^n a_n)}{a_n^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

This implies that for all sufficiently large $n \geqslant  N$,

$$\frac{(-1)^n a_n - \log(1+(-1)^na_n)}{a_n^2} > \frac{1}{4},$$

and

$$\sum_{n=N}^M(-1)^n a_n - \sum_{n=N}^M\log(1+(-1)^na_n) > \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n-N}^Ma_n^2$$

Note that $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ converges by the alternating series test.  If $\sum a_n^2$ diverges, then it diverges to $+\infty$ since each term is nonnegative. This would imply

$$\log \prod_{n=N}^\infty (1+ (-1)^na_n) =\sum_{n=N}^\infty\log(1+(-1)^na_n) = -\infty,$$

and the infinite product diverges to zero, a contradiction.

The convention for infinite products is that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n) = 0$ is considered divergence.

Comment: I am not able to deduce how you deduce   $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^na_n - \log(1+(-1)^n a_n)}{a_n^2} = \frac{1}{2} $ (2nd line of your answer. Kindly explain it

Comment: @Ben: Use $\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$ for $|x|< 1$.  Note that $0 \leqslant a_n <1$ for sufficiently large $n$.